# image is not correctly displayed

Tags: flask

Hello I'm learning flask and I want to insert an image. But the image is not correctly displayed: there is just an icon in the navigator.

I've tried to change the image extension from .png to .jpg but it doesn't change anything. I also tried to change navigator but it stills the same.

The python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/<page_name>/')
def render_static(page_name):
    return render_template(f'{page_name}.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Index</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'image/Android_robot.png')}}" alt = "example" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image should be in `static` folder. Here is an example of how to use static image in Flask template.

Folder structure:

```
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── image
│       └── bitcoin.jpg
└── templates
   └── image_example.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/demo/<page_name>/')
def render_static(page_name):
    return render_template('{page_name}.html'.format(page_name=page_name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Template `image_example.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Index</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>Bitcoin image should be displayed underneath</h2>
    <img height="500px" src="{{url_for('static', filename='image/bitcoin.jpg')}}" alt = "example" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Output of the route `http://127.0.0.1:5000/demo/image_example/`:

[image: static image in Flask example]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to be more careful, the problem was my folder structure.